# Последовательность выполнения jQuery скрипта

Tags: jquery, скрипт, javascript, валидация

есть скрипт `jQuery` для валидации формы и отправки на сервер через `ajax`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($('#email').hasClass('error')){    
        return false
    }
    if($('#name').hasClass('error')){    
        return false
    }
}
$('#customForm').submit(function(e){

    //отменяем стандартное действие при отправке формы
    e.preventDefault();
    //берем из формы метод передачи данных
    var m_method=$(this).attr('method');
    //получаем адрес скрипта на сервере, куда нужно отправить форму
    var m_action=$(this).attr('action');
    //получаем данные, введенные пользователем в формате input1=value1&input2=value2...,
    //то есть в стандартном формате передачи данных формы
    var m_data=$(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: m_method,
        url: m_action,
        data: m_data,
        dataType: "json",                
        success: function(result){  
            $('#addCommentContainer').slideUp("slow");
            $('#tmp-comment').show();                    
            $('#content p').html('<h3>Комментарий добавлен</h3>');
        }
    });
});
```

Мне нужно, что бы пока первый скрипт валидаци не отработает и не вернет `true`, не запускать скрипт отправки (сам скрипт валидации выкладывать не буду, работает он просто, присваивает `error` класс для поля и выводит сообщение )

Comment: Передайте callback в функцию валидации, если он у Вас выполняет какие-то асинхронные действия... Если нет - просто вызовите его перед отправкой ajax-запроса и проверьте результат его работы...

Comment: вот http://jsfiddle.net/yncec/ скрипт отправки и валидации и форма, не могу понять как правильно совместить

Comment: Я поместил событие submit в document.ready. Вроде бы заработало. Попробуйте.

http://jsfiddle.net/REcmT/

Comment: дело в том, что нужно срипт валидации поместиь в один файл, а скрипт отправки должен быть в файле с формой